# Revisão em query

Tags: mysql, query, select

Tenho essa query com intuito de listar os usuários com mais comentários, porém, ela não pode exibir os usuários com a coluna banido=true.

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios a 
INNER JOIN topicos_comentarios b ON a.usuario = b.autor 
WHERE a.banido <> true 
GROUP BY a.usuario 
ORDER BY count(a.usuario) DESC LIMIT 3
```

Esse select foi feito por um amigo daqui, mas não está funcionando. Lista os usuários normalmente incluindo os banidos.

A estrutura da minha tabela usuários:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @Paulo Sérgio Filho, posta o conteúdo da sua tabela `usuarios`, por favor

Comment: Estrutura da tabela usuários: https://prnt.sc/fs0vor

Comment: Estrutura da tabela topicos_comentarios: https://prnt.sc/fs1l1r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique se desta forma funciona:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios a 
INNER JOIN topicos_comentarios b ON a.usuario = b.autor 
WHERE a.banido = 'false'
GROUP BY a.usuario 
ORDER BY count(a.usuario) DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Não funcionou...

Comment: Editei a resposta, agora provavelmente irá funcionar

Comment: Sim, deu certo. Muito obrigado amigo.